# Storing same Key twice but with different values, possible?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase RealtimeDB to store college classes, so by nature classes share the same key.
For instance MATH 101, MATH 102 share the same key but different values since they are different "objects" (per se), but firebase overwrites one with the most resent one.

Is there a way to preserve both key-value pairs or should I look for a different db.

Comment: for realtime use pushID

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database stores data as a JSON structure. Within a JSON structure the keys are unique, so there's no way to have the same key multiple times under a single parent node.

You'll typically want to create multiple child nodes *under* your `MATH 101`, `MATH 102` keys, like:

```
"MATH 101": {
  "-Mlasdj1301201": { ... },
  "-Mlbsdj1301201": { ... }
},
"MATH 102": {
  "-Mkasdj130c201": { ... },
  "-Mzasdj130b201": { ... }
}
```

The `-M...` keys are created by calling `push()` or `childByAutoId()`.